# Why is Big-O time complexity of naive Union-Find algorithm is O(V)?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Let us consider an Edge e with vertices u and v, also I keep track of the top-most parent of every node included in the spanning tree.

Now, if I try to find out the top-most parent of vertex u or v. The worst that could happen is that parent of u is some q. But if q is included in the spanning tree then its top-most parent must be a single node representing that connected component.

I mean in that case we don't have to hop around from u to q, q to w, w to s ... so on to reach the top-most parent, because the top-most parent of q will be the top-most parent of u also.

So, I am just trying to say that maybe the time complexity of the union-find algorithm is not O(V) where V is the number of vertices. But maybe it just have constant time complexity.

Comment: How do you make sure that every vertex always has a pointer to the *top-most* parent? This requires many updates with every union operation: you'd have to update every vertex in one of the components you're joining.

Comment: When I am adding an edge e to the spanning tree S whose parent node till now let's say be q. Then no matter which edge I am adding e to, all of them will be pointing to q. Now I add e and make the parent of e as q. So you can say that I added a new edge whose parent is q. So everytime I add a new edge, the other vertex parent will be q.

Comment: Suppose you add edge $uv$; $u$'s parent node is $q$, and $v$'s parent node is $r$. It's not enough to change $v$'s parent node to $q$ (or $r$'s parent node to $q$); what about all the other nodes whose parent is $r$?

Comment: If you are talking about all the nodes in the connected component whose top-most parent is q; then you can just get r as their parent because while adding _uv_ edge; we would have changed the parent of q as r. So those nodes will point to q which will point to r.

Comment: So now you have nodes which point to $q$ which point to $r$. If you now do another union between nodes with top-most parents $r$ and $s$, you can end up with nodes which point to $q$ which point to $r$ which point to $s$, etc...

Comment: Can you please give me a concrete example of the worst case? I mean it should take V or almost V hops to find the top-most parents.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130126/discussion-between-eshu-manohare-and-misha-lavrov).

Answer (score 1):

If the data is such that the root of your spanning tree (and the roots of all subtrees) may be chosen arbitrarily, and node deletions are rare enough, then you may do what you are suggesting to achieve amortized time complexity of O(1) by keeping the root of your spanning tree fixed (except when root is to be deleted) and adding an extra pointer in each node that points to the root node.

Notice that this depends on multiple assumptions that may not be true in practice. Note also that this possible time savings comes at a cost to space. If the assumptions hold, you still have to make a judgement call on whether the small extra cost of space is worth the small savings on processing time.